# Selenium select first datepicker is working but not selecting the second

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I'm creating tests and I've an issue with Selenium. I'm trying to set the date of two datepickers, one to select a starting date and the other to select an ending date. The two datepickers are on the same page, side by side. Here's the java code I'm using :

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("date_debut")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(String.valueOf(10))).click();

    // inserted to see if selecting another element would make it work
    driver.findElement(By.name("nom_projet")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("date_fin_prevu")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(String.valueOf(17))).click();
```

I'm sure that the id's of the datepickers are good and that the datepickers are selectable because the first one I want to select is always selectable. The issue is that I can't select the first one, set the date and then select the second one to set the date.

In a few words, my issue is that the second datepicker is never selected.

I hope I've been clear, if not ask me for explainations.

Comment: I think it depends on what 'datepicker' you are using. could you add more info?

Comment: did you involved some wait between the date picker selection?

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot I'm using jQuery datepickers. I think that the issue is coming from Selenium because it works perfectly when I use my code for only one of the datepickers.

Comment: @KumrunNaharKeya I tried using Thread.sleep() but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you please share the UI element and div information so that I can execute from my end

Comment: @Snyler I'm not familiar with the jQuery datepicker. if there's an underlying `input` element, you could try `sendKeys` on it.

Comment: @KumrunNaharKeya Here's a jsfiddle with my code https://jsfiddle.net/Snyler/9m4296w3/5/
I'm using CakePHP framework so I copy paste you the html generated via the form helper of CakePHP. I also added you the Angular directive added by my team mate to manage the date interval. However, I tried removing the angular directive and it's still not working.

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot We're using an input element (see my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Snyler/9m4296w3/5/) but we don't allow users to write in it so I'm not able to use the sendkeys method. I don't figure out why the first click is working perfectly - no matter which datepicker is the target, I can start by ending date it will work but then I won't be able to select the starting date and vice versa - but the second never works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that the click on the second element triggers the close of the first datepicker and not initializing correctly the second one.
Try a random click on body on the way

```
driver.findElement(By.css("body")).click();
```

before clicking the second datepicker.

Comment: You're right, it's working with this line. However I don't understand why this work and why clicking on a random field of the page I completed before doesn't do the job, like in my example ... Nevertheless, thanks a lot !

Comment: As Sebastian has correctly explained, clicking on the second element actually closes the first datepicker and doesn not trigger a click on the next element (which opens a second datepicker). Hence, the above code does that for you; clicks on the body element which triggers a click outside and then the further code for clicking  a datepicker, and selecting a date works :)

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand it this way, for me clicking somewhere else was enough. Thanks for your explainations :)